# NameError (uninitialized constant nameController::nameService):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create search form, Is this the correct way and correct naming convention?

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts

  scope 'post' do
    get 'search',                                 to: 'posts#search'
  end


end
```

posts_controller

```
  def search
    @posts = []
    word = search_params[:word]
    @posts = SearchService.new(word).search
    render 'searcch_results'
  end
```

search_service.rb

```
class SearchService
end
```

Comment: What version of rails, what is the path to the SearchService file?

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code which refers to nameController::nameService?

Comment: @dbugger inside app/services

Comment: @ramblex I meant the name is postsController, searchService